# facebook Like button not showing for jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I followed the [tutorial for integrating facebook in my webapp, using jquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery) . Then I wanted to add a `like button` following [this tutorial snippet](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2#plugins) But it is not working.

My webapplication and javascript code, is available at [www.stretchsketch.com](http://www.stretchsketch.com)

The relevant part in my html page looks like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
   $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
        appId: 'MY APPID',
    });     
    $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function() {alert('loginned')});
});
</script>
....
</div>
<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-send="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.js"></script>
<!-- some more js files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`$( document ).ready( function() {` is not defined on the page itself but in a separate javascript document, (js/stretchsketch.js) (see [here](http://www.stretchsketch.com/js/stretchsketch.js)) referred to by the main html document. I see the that `#fb-root div` gets created, iframes appended etc, but the like button is not visible. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The code you've posted is not useful. Try stripping down the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the error, then posting the relevant code here. Not only will that help people on the site troubleshoot the issue, it may lead to you being able to diagnose the problem yourself.

Comment: need to add `xfbml:true` to the FB.init argument object to render plugins.